# python: Prune Redundant Tuples / Subsets in Collection

Tags: python, nltk

I've got a list of natural language ngrams that are collected into a list of tuples of various sizes.

I want to prune the list to remove redundant ngrams - remove tuples that are a subset of any other, so that I have a list of the largest unique ngrams in the collection.

In this list of tuples

```
[('more', 'red', 'fish'), 
('my', 'favorite', 'red', 'fish'), 
('these', 'fish', 'are', 'blue'), 
('red', 'fish'),              # <--- Remove
('blue', 'are'),              # <--- Don't Remove - order not same in other tuple
('purple', 'sharks'), 
('red', 'fish', 'eat', 'seaweed'),
('my', 'favorite'),           # <--- Remove
('fish', 'eat', 'seaweed'),   # <--- Remove
('that', 'fish', 'red', 'no')]
```

For example, I'd like to remove ('red', 'fish'), ('my', 'favorite'), and ('fish', 'eat', 'seaweed') from the list because they occur, in order, in some of the other tuples.

I can do this as a messy iteration over the whole list of tuples, but that seems inefficient for this large multi-GB data set.  Sets / subsets are not sensitive to item order, so didn't seem appropriate.  What's the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the each tuple into a list of strings and then try to check if string 1 is present inside string 2, if yes then remove it.

It will be also inefficient but clean, try to join with space or comma, then search.

Comment: Good idea!   Substring matching is pretty quick, though the source string will always appear in the larger string at least once, so a duplicate would be when the substring appears 2 or more times in the big string.